# Error loading a compiled jasper file inside .war file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, war

I have a problem trying to load a **.jasper subReport** that is inside a .war file.
The idea is to load a subReport that is inside "parte1" folder.

[image: my .war file]

In [documentation](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/understanding-subreports) says that you can't pass relative path to load a subReport file ...

> You can't use a relative path to locate the subreport file; that is if you have a report in c:\myreport\main_report.jasper, you cannot refer to a subreport using an expression like ..\mysubreports\mysubreport.jasper.
>
> This is because JasperReports does not keep in memory the original location of the Jasper file that it’s working with. This makes perfect sense, considering that a Jasper object is not necessarily loaded from a physical file.

So I'm trying to pass a full path to the .jasper file.
1.- I'm getting the context using @Autowired and then completing the path as a String...

```
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", contextPath + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "report" + File.separator + "parte1" + File.separator);
```

2.- Pass the path to jasperReport as a parameter

```
printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(getPath(sourceFileName), parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstDataSource));
```

3.- give the path to load the subReport file

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement x="50" y="50" width="200" height="200" uuid="ced7076b-b6ba-4973-8e4c-cd289bd77c4e"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{motivoReclamo})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ClsMotivoReclamoReportBean.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

but, when try to run it. It displays this error message ...

> 2019-01-15 05:29:19 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] ERROR xxx.xxx.xx.report.PDFGenerator - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\xxxxxxxxx\WEB-INF\report\parte1\ClsMotivoReclamoReportBean.jasper.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**UPDATE**

*I'm using Spring Boot and generating a .war file*

I'm using this maven plugin to compile the reports and generate the .jasper file.
https://github.com/alexnederlof/Jasper-report-maven-plugin
Then I use this maven plugin to copy some images needed in the report ...

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/report</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/jasperfiles</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*.jrxml</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And then I use this maven plugin to copy the jasper files into .war

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/report</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/report</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively define the sub report as InputStream:

In your JRXML:

```
<parameter name="MY_SUB_REPORT" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false"/>
  ...
</subreport>
  ...
  <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{MY_SUB_REPORT}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

In your Java Class:

```
parameters.put("MY_SUB_REPORT", new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(path)));
```

Comment: now it throws    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream. Few lines below ... **Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF**

Comment: Maybe your jasper is somehow corrupted? Do you use Maven filtering on your resources packaged into the .war? Possibly this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078820/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-efbfbdef#24118076

Comment: thanks for the answer, check my update. Suddenly if I put the maven code suggested in that answer it breaks all my code.